# Integrate of diferential of modulus of a complex function.

Tags: integration, derivatives

Let $u(x,t):\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be a diferentiable function square integrable. So I want to calculate
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{d}{dt}|u|^2dx.$$
I know that the diferential of the modulus is not well defined in that case, but if we define $|u|^2=u\bar{u}$ we have:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{d}{dt}(u\bar{u})=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}u_t\bar{u}+u\bar{u_t}dx,$$
my questions is: why is this well defined (many books use that)? If $u$ in infinity goes to zero I can use integration by parts to conclude that:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}u_t\bar{u}+u\bar{u_t}dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}u_t\bar{u}-u_t\bar{u}dx=0?$$